# 'error {badmatch,{error,enoent}}' occurred executing push_roster command on ejabberd

Tags: erlang, xmpp, ejabberd

I am trying to add bulk contacts to user's roster in ejabberd. I am using default Mnesia database with ejabberd.
I have created a file sampleRosterFile. In this file contents are

```
[{"kunal", "localhost", "Friend List", "kunal"},{"Rich", "localhost", "Friend List", "Rich"}]
```

I am executing command

```
sudo ejabberdctl push_roster /home/kunal/Projects/demo/sampleRosterFile kunal localhost
```

But i am getting error

```
Problem 'error {badmatch,{error,enoent}}' occurred executing the command.
Stacktrace: [{mod_admin_extra,push_roster,3,
                              [{file,"src/mod_admin_extra.erl"},{line,1145}]},
             {ejabberd_commands,execute_command2,2,
                                [{file,"src/ejabberd_commands.erl"},
                                 {line,410}]},
             {ejabberd_ctl,call_command,3,
                           [{file,"src/ejabberd_ctl.erl"},{line,295}]},
             {ejabberd_ctl,try_call_command,3,
                           [{file,"src/ejabberd_ctl.erl"},{line,271}]},
             {ejabberd_ctl,process2,3,
                           [{file,"src/ejabberd_ctl.erl"},{line,220}]},
             {ejabberd_ctl,process,1,
                           [{file,"src/ejabberd_ctl.erl"},{line,205}]},
             {rpc,'-handle_call_call/6-fun-0-',5,
                  [{file,"rpc.erl"},{line,206}]}]
```

As per recent developments, i have made my roster file to .txt and tried again. but now that is giving me error something related to string

```
sudo ejabberdctl push_roster /home/kunal/Projects/demo/ejabberd/ebin/sampleRosterFile.txt kunal localhost
Problem 'error function_clause' occurred executing the command.
Stacktrace: [{jid,to_string,[error],[{file,"src/jid.erl"},{line,134}]},
             {mod_admin_extra,build_roster_item,3,
                              [{file,"src/mod_admin_extra.erl"},{line,1200}]},
             {mod_admin_extra,subscribe,8,
                              [{file,"src/mod_admin_extra.erl"},{line,1088}]},
             {mod_admin_extra,subscribe_roster,2,
                              [{file,"src/mod_admin_extra.erl"},{line,1167}]},
             {ejabberd_commands,execute_command2,2,
                                [{file,"src/ejabberd_commands.erl"},
                                 {line,410}]},
             {ejabberd_ctl,call_command,3,
                           [{file,"src/ejabberd_ctl.erl"},{line,295}]},
             {ejabberd_ctl,try_call_command,3,
                           [{file,"src/ejabberd_ctl.erl"},{line,271}]},
             {ejabberd_ctl,process2,3,
                           [{file,"src/ejabberd_ctl.erl"},{line,220}]}]
```

Need help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Earlier code was giving me `enoent` error, which was correctly pointed out by @Mickaël Rémond
It will be helpful to give full path of the roster file.

Next is `error function_clause` error which mean that **no function or signature is matching with my input**.

after debugging found that correct file format for push_roster command in mod_admin_extra is

```
[{<<"admin">>,<<"localhost">>,<<"Friend">>,<<"Admin">>},{<<"anil">>,<<"localhost">>,<<"Friend">>,<<"Anil">>}]
```

It finally worked.

I found helpful explaination on the blog http://www.techiekunal.in/2016/04/ejabberd-bulk-roster-addition-using-pushroster.html

Comment: Thanks for this!  I am trying to follow this suggested format, but I am still getting a similar error:
Problem 'error {badmatch,{error,enoent}}' occurred executing the command.
Stacktrace: [{mod_admin_extra,push_roster,3,
                              [{file,"src/mod_admin_extra.erl"},{line,1135}]},
Also, I found a link with some documentation here:
https://svn.process-one.net/ejabberd-modules/mod_admin_extra/trunk/README.txt
Any idea what is going on for me?
Here is my sample format:
[{"testuser1","dcollier-devlt","guardians","Test1"}]

Comment: I figured my problem out.  It was trying to read the file from: C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\ejabberd\database\mnesia\
So I just had to either put the file there or give it a specific path
I am using windows and used procmon to see/verify the file not found error.

Answer (score 5):

`enoent` error means the file cannot be found. You likely made a mistake in your command and the roster file cannot be found or the ejabberd user does not have the right to read it.

Comment: I have tried giving full permissions to roster file but same error coming. Is there any required file format or location where i need to put roster file in ejabberd ?

Comment: I have successfully read roster file but now next error is coming like `Problem 'error function_clause' occurred executing the command.`